# Beginning Python - Calculating Area of a Circle

Tags: python

For starters I am using Pyscripter ver. 2.6.0.0 x64 with Python ver. 3.3.0 x64

I'm taking a beginning python course and I'm completely stumped. I was given this question:

Write a function called calculateArea.  The function should take a parameter that represents the radius of a circle and should return the area of the circle.  Write a program that asks the user to enter the number of circles.  The program should then display a chart that lists the radius of the circle and it's area beginning at 1 and continuing up to and including the number entered by the user.

This is the progress I've made so far:

```
def calculateArea(radius):
    pi = 3.141
    area = (pi * (radius ** 2))
    return area

n = int(input("Please enter the amount of circles you wish to test."))

#r = float(input("Please enter the circle's radius."))

area = calculateArea(n)

#print("The area of the circle with a radius of:", r, "equals:", area)

print("Circle('s)","  ","Radius Given","  ", "Calculated Area")
print("**********", "  ", "************", "  ", "***************")

for x in range(1, n+1):
    print(x, "     ","     ", "    ","          ", area)
```

This is my current output when I input for 5 circles to test:

```
>>> 
Circle('s)    Radius Given    Calculated Area
**********    ************    ***************
1                             78.525
2                             78.525
3                             78.525
4                             78.525
5                             78.525
>>>
```

What I'm trying to figure out at the moment is how to a fix the output where it calculates the area from my input of n for circles tested. Then I need help with trying to get the radius to display/work. When I used r to have a user input a beginning radius I kept getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 420, in run_nodebug
  File "<module1>", line 28, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: What was the user typing in as `r`?

Comment: If I were to un-comment r then the user would input a float value for the radius of a circle.

Comment: The code doesn't give an error, even when uncommenting out your lines and changing `calculateArea(n)` to `calculateArea(r)`

Comment: A thought I just had is that because I use n as a variable then when I say that variable area = calculateArea(n) <--- Does that cause conflict?

Comment: As a side note, you shouldn't declare your own `pi`. `import` the `math` module and then you can use `math.pi` which is more accurate than your variable.

Comment: If your user enters 4.5. What must be output? 1,2,3,4? what about 0.5?

Comment: @Bert  - I didn't even know there was a math module for pi... I was never taught that/haven't been taught that yet.

Comment: @Priyesh Kumar - I don't know how to answer that. I'm only doing this based off of what the class I'm in has done. The teacher hasn't given enough pretext about this issue. If I were to guess then I would say make a piece of script that flags an error if the user inputs a decimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the job:

```
import math
def calculateArea(radius):
    area = (math.pi * (radius**2))
    return area

n = int(input("Please enter the amount of circles you wish to test: "))

print("{:10} {:15} {:15}".format("Circle('s)","Radius Given","Calculated Area") )
print("{:10} {:15} {:15}".format("-"*10,"-"*15,"-"*15) )


for x in range(1, n + 1):
    print("{:10} {:15} {:15}".format(x, x, calculateArea(x)) )
```

Output:

```
Please enter the amount of circles you wish to test: 15
Circle('s) Radius Given    Calculated Area
---------- --------------- ---------------
         1               1   3.14159265359
         2               2   12.5663706144
         3               3   28.2743338823
         4               4   50.2654824574
         5               5   78.5398163397
         6               6   113.097335529
         7               7   153.938040026
         8               8    201.06192983
         9               9   254.469004941
        10              10   314.159265359
        11              11   380.132711084
        12              12   452.389342117
        13              13   530.929158457
        14              14   615.752160104
        15              15   706.858347058
```

Comment: The number of circles should be a `int` instead of a `float`. Parenthesis in the formula are not necessary. You can use `math.pi` to have better precision.

Comment: yeah, I am waiting for more info from OP, then will edit it

Comment: I think it's too late ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I see from your edits how I was supposed to properly write the script. What you have written is still a bit to advanced for me however.

Comment: Learning can never ends!